# What does git_sysdir_find_in_dirlist() in libgit2 do?

Tags: c, git, libgit2

I'm working on porting some logic from libgit2 into Go, but not a 1:1 port as Go works differently. I think this function scans a directory tree, but I'm not sure.

```c
static int git_sysdir_find_in_dirlist(
    git_buf *path,
    const char *name,
    git_sysdir_t which,
    const char *label)
{
    // allocations
    size_t len;
    const char *scan, *next = NULL;
    const git_buf *syspath;

    // check the path to make sure it exists?
    GIT_ERROR_CHECK_ERROR(git_sysdir_get(&syspath, which));
    if (!syspath || !git_buf_len(syspath))
        goto done;

    // this is the part I don't understand
    for (scan = git_buf_cstr(syspath); scan; scan = next) {
        /* find unescaped separator or end of string */
        for (next = scan; *next; ++next) {
            if (*next == GIT_PATH_LIST_SEPARATOR &&
                (next <= scan || next[-1] != '\\'))
                break;
        }

        len = (size_t)(next - scan);
        next = (*next ? next + 1 : NULL);
        if (!len)
            continue;

        GIT_ERROR_CHECK_ERROR(git_buf_set(path, scan, len));
        if (name)
            GIT_ERROR_CHECK_ERROR(git_buf_joinpath(path, path->ptr, name));

        if (git_path_exists(path->ptr))
            return 0;
    }

done:
    git_buf_dispose(path);
    git_error_set(GIT_ERROR_OS, "the %s file '%s' doesn't exist", label, name);
    return GIT_ENOTFOUND;
}
```

It's the for loop that's confusing me. `for (scan = git_buf_cstr(syspath); scan; scan = next) { ... }` looks like it's iterating/scanning `syspath`, and then I get totally lost at `for (scan = git_buf_cstr(syspath); scan; scan = next) { ... }`.

What does this function specifically do?

Answer (score 0):

This is not looking at a directory *tree* but rather at delimited string containing a list of *directories*.  For instance (though this clearly isn't aimed at this particular case), as [the top level documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git/) says:

> **GIT_ALTERNATE_OBJECT_DIRECTORIES**
>   Due to the immutable nature of Git objects, old objects can be
>    archived into shared, read-only directories. This variable
>    specifies a ":" separated (on Windows ";" separated) list of Git
>    object directories which can be used to search for Git objects. New
>    objects will not be written to these directories.
>
> Entries that begin with " (double-quote) will be interpreted as
>    C-style quoted paths, removing leading and trailing double-quotes
>    and respecting backslash escapes. E.g., the value
>    **"path-with-\"-and-:-in-it":vanilla-path** has two paths:
>    **path-with-"-and-:-in-it** and **vanilla-path**.

The function is obviously scanning a character-separated path list (whatever that character is—probably colon or semicolon as above), checking for backslash prefixes, so that you can write `/a:C\:/a` to allow the thing to look into either `/a` or `C:/a`.

Answer (score 0):

This function is tasked with locating the file `name` inside a "configuration level", (ie. `~/.git/`, `/etc/git`, see [git_sysdir_t](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/master/src/sysdir.h#L78) for a list of known locations). As those levels are stored as a bunch of static ("readonly") `/` (or `\`)-separated C strings, and we can't modify that at runtime, we have to jump through hoops to what amounts to a foreach-string loop.